# How can I delete a broken message from the ActiveMQ Artemis journal?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.23.1.

An error occurred after restarting the Artemis service:

```
AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ID:ccd0bbcb-0db0-11ed-b640-00505685831b"
```

I found the journal that contains this string, but I couldn't find the string itself, and I don't know how to remove the line from the log.

How can I find a line in the journals and delete/repair it so as not to lose data by deleting the journals.

```
2022-08-05 10:09:33,954 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ID:ccd0bbcb-0db0-11ed-b640-00505685831b"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.collections.TypedProperties.getLongProperty(TypedProperties.java:258) [artemis-commons-2.23.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage.getLongProperty(CoreMessage.java:1004) [artemis-core-client-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.parseLargeMessage(JournalStorageManager.java:372) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.lambda$loadMessageJournal$3(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:966) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.collections.SparseArrayLinkedList$SparseArray.clear(SparseArrayLinkedList.java:114) [artemis-commons-2.23.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.collections.SparseArrayLinkedList.clearSparseArrayList(SparseArrayLinkedList.java:173) [artemis-commons-2.23.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.collections.SparseArrayLinkedList.clear(SparseArrayLinkedList.java:227) [artemis-commons-2.23.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.loadMessageJournal(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:935) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.loadJournals(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3606) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart2(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3269) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:76) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:663) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:571) [artemis-server-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:64) [artemis-cli-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:127) [artemis-cli-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:160) [artemis-cli-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:108) [artemis-cli-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:135) [artemis-cli-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [java.base:]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [java.base:]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134) [artemis-boot.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50) [artemis-boot.jar:2.23.1]
```

**Broken Message.**
I exported the data from the journals and deleted everything but the broken message. Imported it into pure ArtemisMQ and got an error when running on value "_AMQ_ORIG_MESSAGE_ID". Can someone explain what is the problem with this value?

```html
<activemq-journal>
   <bindings>
      <address-binding routing-types="ANYCAST" name="INT.TEST.PF.CREATE.RESP.ERR" id="2172626911"/>
      <queue-binding address="INT.TEST.PF.CREATE.RESP.ERR" filter-string="" name="INT.TEST.PF.CREATE.RESP.ERR" id="2172626912" routing-type="ANYCAST"/>
   </bindings>
   <messages>
      <message id="2172626917" priority="4" expiration="0" timestamp="1658928854636" type="bytes" user-id="ce631ba7-0db0-11ed-ad0e-00505685eec9">
         <properties>
            <property name="_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE" value="1" type="byte"/>
            <property name="PFFileName" value="2022-07-27T16:34:11.925123.pdf" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="PFSystemName" value="TEST_REG" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="JMSCorrelationID" value="ID:cae19602-0db0-11ed-ad0e-00505685eec9" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="_AMQ_VALIDATED_USER" value="test-pf-acc" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="_AMQ_ORIG_MESSAGE_ID" value="ID:ccd0bbcb-0db0-11ed-b640-00505685831b" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="PFProcessId" value="f59fb998-7b58-4448-9bc6-6327eaefb243_0:1" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE" value="121886" type="long"/>
            <property name="traceparent" value="00-00000000000000006a2fc50eb4583663-becee71cc630eb5b-01" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="__AMQ_CID" value="c7910b66-0db0-11ed-ad0e-00505685eec9" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="baggage" value="sessionId=2ababb61-48fa-43b0-8a31-a17a9a57939c" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="JMSXDeliveryCount" value="0" type="long"/>
            <property name="_AMQ_ORIG_QUEUE" value="INT.TEST.PF.CREATE.RESP" type="simple-string"/>
            <property name="_AMQ_ORIG_ADDRESS" value="INT.TEST.PF.CREATE.RESP" type="simple-string"/>
         </properties>
         <queues>
            <queue name="INT.TEST.PF.CREATE.RESP.ERR"/>
         </queues>
         <body isLarge="true">
         </body>
      </message>
   </messages>
</activemq-journal>
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack-trace? This looks to me like it may be a bug.

Comment: added to main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any recourse here aside from applying a patch to correct the underlying issue (if that's even possible). There is no tool to manually modify the file-based journal directly. Typically I'd recommend using the `data exp` command to pull all the data out into an XML file, modifying the XML as necessary, deleting/moving the broker's journal, and then using the `data imp` command put push all the data back. However, if you can't even start the broker then this would be possible.

Comment: I will try today and let you know

Comment: added broken message